# Get user detail from TwitterOAut (Like email, birthdate and name)

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-oauth

I am stuck how to get detail data from twitter API. I am  using [this library](https://github.com/MunGell/Codeigniter-TwitterOAuth)

I have success until user can login, but i can't get detail user who login like (full name, email and birth date) i just can get (Username and user_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter api doesn't return these values full name, email and birth date, you can get screen_name and user_id, for full name and email you can handle it manually

Comment: Yep. Check the documentation to see what details can be returned with user object: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show